# error: cannot find symbol variable viewpager ---Androidx

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have the following code, the project is migrated to andoidx, `R.id.viewpager` returns `can not find symbol variable viewpager` `SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter` is a custom(an extention of) 
`FragmentPagerAdapter` and is working well

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catagory);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
    SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set the adapter onto the view pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

Comment: can you upload here your activity_category.xml file ?

Comment: it is a simple linear layoutb intended to Fragments with their own xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>`

Comment: where is the viewPager ? in the activity of fragment layout ?

Comment: solved . Thank you! used the wrong xml layout changed code in activity main